# Hiding previously submitted survey points on Crowdsource Reporter?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123, crowdsourcing

Is there a way to hide previously submitted survey points on the maps in Crowdsource reporter?

My project involves having users point locations on the map where infrastructure may impact biodiversity and have them fill in survey questions as attributes. Just to provide more context, my initial idea was to have a survey form with several sections each containing a geopoint function. But since survey123 only supports one geopoint per form, I created several surveys based on each section and incorporated them into CR to allow pointing locations for each survey section in one platform as opposed to having several separate forms to fill.

But the problem arises as we would like to treat this platform as similar to a normal survey as possible where each survey/response is a unique entry while keeping them confidential at the same time (due to demographic related questions). Hence it's best if we could just hide previously submitted survey points. I have tried seeing if crowdsource reporter is configurable but so far there are no options.

Is there a function that can achieve this? Or any ideas which ArcGIS online platform or web apps that can support this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up [hosted feature layer views](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/create-hosted-views.htm) for each feature service related to your forms. You will need at least 2 feature layer views:

1. For public editing (otherwise known as fieldworker) - this layer should be set up to allow users to add new features, but only allow them to see their own records.
2. For internal use only (otherwise known as stakeholder) - this layer is shared only with your organisation or a group. All records are visible and you can enable full editing.

Survey123 web will (to some degree) generate these layers for you when you set up the collaboration settings. Go to [survey123.arcgis.com](https://survey123.arcgis.com) and navigate to your survey. Go to the 'Collaborate' tab. For Submitter, select 'Everyone (Public)' and click save. For Viewer, select 'Members of my organization' and click save. When you go back to your 'My Content' page, you should now see two new hosted feature layer views have been generated called fieldworker and stakeholder (as above).